# Structure of the proof of the fundamental theorem of arithmetics

Tags: ring-theory, arithmetic

**Fundamental theorem of arithmetics**: A principal ideal domain is factorial. i.e: Any non zero element of a principal ideal domain can be decomposed in a unique product of irreductibles.

**The structure of the proof goes like this::**

- *Proof of the existence of a decomposition:* In this part, it is shown any non-zero and non-invertible elements of a principal ideal domain can be decomposed in a product of irrreductibles.
- *Proof of the uniqueness*

**My problem**: In the first part they show that any non-zero and non-invertible elements of a principal ideal domain can be decomposed in a product of irrreductibles. **What about non-zero but invertible elements of a principal ideal domain?**

Answer (score 1):

In a commutative ring $R$, say that $a\sim b$ if there exists a unit $u$ such that $a=bu$. ($a$ is said to be 'an associate to $b$'.) This turns out to be an equivalence relation.

In the theory of unique factorization, when you say a particular factorziaton is a "unique product," it is subject to the caveat that things are unique *up to being associates.*

Now you can verify that the set of units of the ring forms an equivalence class in this relation, so that every unit is equivalent to $1$. Therefore, it's pointless to talk about factorizations of units because all units are "the same as $1$."